# Deploying a new model to a sagemaker endpoint without updating the config?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker, mlops

I want to deploy a new model to an existing AWS SageMaker endpoint. The model is trained by a different pipeline and stored as a mode.tar.gz in S3. The sagemaker endpoint config is pointing to this as the model data URL. Sagemaker however doesn't reload the model and I don't know how to convince it to do so.

I want to deploy a new model to an AWS SageMaker endpoint. The model is trained by a different pipeline and stored as a mode.tar.gz in S3. I provisioned the Sagemaker Endpoint using AWS CDK. Now, within the training pipeline, I want to allow the data scientists to optionally upload their newly trained model to the endpoint for testing. I dont want to create a new model or an endpoint config. Also, I dont want to change the infrastructure (AWS CDK) code.

The model is uploaded to the S3 location that the sagemaker endpoint config is using as the
`model_data_url`. Hence it should use the new model. But it doesn't load it. I know that Sagemaker caches models inside the container, but idk how to force a new load.

[This documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/add-models-to-endpoint.html)  suggests to store the model tarball with another name in the same S3 folder, and alter the code to invoke the model. This is not possible for my application. And I dont want Sagemaker to default to an old model, once the `TargetModel` parameter is not present.

Here is what I am currently doing after uploading the model to S3. Even though the endpoint transitions into *Updating* state, it does not force a model reload:

```py
def update_sm_endpoint(endpoint_name: str) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    """Forces the sagemaker endpoint to reload model from s3"""
    sm = boto3.client("sagemaker")
    return sm.update_endpoint_weights_and_capacities(
        EndpointName=endpoint_name,
        DesiredWeightsAndCapacities=[
            {"VariantName": "main", "DesiredWeight": 1},
        ],
    )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the model called in a SageMaker endpoint, you have to create a new model object and and new endpoint configuration. Then call [update_endpoint](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.update_endpoint) This will not change the name of the endpoint.

comments on your question and SageMaker doc:

- the documentation you mention (*"This documentation suggests to store the model tarball with another name in the same S3 folder, and alter the code to invoke the model"*) is for SageMaker Multi-Model Endpoint, a service to store multiple models in the same endpoint in parallel. This is not what you need. You need a single-model SageMaker endpoint, and that you update with a
- also, the API you mention `sm.update_endpoint_weights_and_capacities` is not needed for what you want (unless you want a progressive rollout from the traffic from model 1 to model 2).